# Is this mold growing on my shower ceiling?

Tags: bathroom, ceiling, mold

[image]

Is this dark stuff above my shower mold?  If so, how should I go about removing it?  I live in an apartment, so I doubt I could go on with scraping it off and the like without upsetting maintenance, not to mention upsetting the people living above me with the noise of scraping the ceiling.

Comment: Have you tried a bleach/water solution?

Comment: Also, as for upsetting maintenance, shouldn't they actually be taking care of this for you if you're renting an apartment?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that scraping paint of the celling would upset anyone, unless someone has hearing devices on your celling :) I suggest that you scrap it off, clean the surface with bleach or something like that and then repaint it. But the real question is what is causing this mold? My first guess is that you are not ventilating, or not ventilating bathroom enough and this is causing humidity, leading to mold. If paint on the wall is washable, maybe you can go without scraping, just with bleaching and venting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is mould. its from the high humidity in the shower area.

If you have a window, I would leave it open after showers, or better yet, install an extractor fan.

You can remove the mould by getting some 20% Hydrogen Peroxide and diluting it into a spray bottle... just spray on mould and it should go away.

I would add about 10% hydrogen peroxide to your spray bottle. you should see bubbles forming on the mould. The nice thing about H2O2 is that it basically reacts into water and Oxygen, it kills the mould by excess oxygen. so you dont have to worry about unsafe chemicals in your shower.. the only risk is if you used too strong of a mix (more than 30%) H202 of the solution.

Comment: The bathroom is in the middle of the apartment, so no windows.  There is a fan, and I run it for the duration of my showers, plus 5-15 minutes afterwards.  I have a bottle of H2O2, but its only 3%.  Would it be effective at all, or just a waste of H2O2 to spray it?

Comment: 3% would also be effective,Just try to use more, you will know its working if white foam appears on the mould after  a few minutes.